# TensorFlow in PyCharm value error: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I am referring TensorFlow speciliazation from Coursera where a certain piece of code works absolutely fine in Google Colab, whereas when I try to run it locally on PyCharm, it gives following error:

**Failed to find data adapter that can handle input**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please include some code and where the error occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you tell me the code where the error occurred?
It should be available in logs under your PyCharm console.

Looking at your comments, it seems that the model is expecting an array while you provided a list.

I was facing the same issue. Turns out it was a in the form of a list. I had to convert the fields into a numpy array like:

```
training_padded = np.array(training_padded)
training_labels = np.array(training_labels)
testing_padded = np.array(testing_padded)
testing_labels = np.array(testing_labels)
```

thats it!

Try it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: history = model.fit(t, tt, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=(v, vv), verbose=1)

Comment: Oh I see, got it. the problem is with list and array.